# First and last day of next month ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Stuck trying to figure out how to find the first and last day of the next month, the month after that and then again after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For first day of next month:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1)
```

For last day next month:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)
```

One month after the current month:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(2)
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(3).AddDays(-1)
```

Two months after the current month:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(3)
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(4).AddDays(-1)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If i could hug you I would. thank you you are a scholar and a gentleman